# printing json array data without looping using key in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$c_array on printing gives below data
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Category_Name] => sample quiz question 1 [Score] => 50 ) [1] =>         Array ( [Category_Name] => sample quiz question 1 [Score] => 100 ) )
```

/*json encoding array*/

```
$jse= json_encode($c_array);

 echo $jse;
```

/*On echoing $jse i get this below json data */

```
[{"Category_Name":"sample quiz question 1","Score":"50"},{"Category_Name":"sample quiz question 2","Score":"100"}]
```

What i need is just below output

**sample quiz question 1 

sample quiz question 2**

without key "Category_Name" while echoing 
and I wanted it to be done **without using foreach loop or print_r** (just only using echo)

how can i do this ?Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: why you dont want to get value by key

Comment: without foreach, without for, without php ? lol. Just use foreach with the original array (not json)

Comment: I dont want key to get printed in output..only value needs to be printed.But i have no problem in using key to obtain value..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get only names :

```
$array = array(
  array(
    'Category_Name' => 'sample quiz question 1',
    'score' => 50
  ),
  array(
    'Category_Name' => 'sample quiz question 2',
    'score' => 100
  )
  // ...
);

function getName($array) {
  return $array['Category_Name'];
}

$result = array_map("getName", $array);
```

If you want to print values only, you can use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) :

```
function printName($array) {
  echo $array['Category_Name']."\n";
}

$result = array_walk($array, "printName");
```